# TB-Mega menu close open by click problem

Tags: navigation

I have a problem about TB-MegaMenu navigation bar.

I use this script for get an open/close by click system :

[tb-megamenu how to click to open/close sub menu in mobile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200311/tb-megamenu-how-to-click-to-open-close-sub-menu-in-mobile)

It works well but when i show a submenu no links works, for example:

- Menu 1

  - submenu 1 (==> http://www.google.com)
  - submenu 2 (==> http://www.yahoo.com)

I show the submenu by clicking on Menu 1 and when i click on submenu 1 or 2 , i get no redirection in google or yahoo and it's same for mobile version.

Thanks for your help ;)