# TB Mega Menu - how to open sub menu on click not hover (desktop version)?

Tags: 7, javascript

For some reasons I need to open the mega menu when somebody clicks on a menu item - for the desktop version.

At the moment the mega menu opens with hover, I need a solution for click opening.

Is there any solution within the TB Mega Menu module for this?
If not, how can I realize this with JQuery?

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of "[tb-megamenu how to click to open/close sub menu in mobile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200311)", because I need the click behavior NOT for mobile version but for desktop version.